# Saving structured data in android

Tags: java, android, storage

Android provides some ways to save application information. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Now, my issue is that I have some structured data comparable with tasks, that have categories and some other related settings. Everything is fetched from a web service and has to get saved for performance and offline use.

Which would be the best option to use on Android? I think the choice is really between SQLite Database or Internal storage. What would I expect from the performance and implementation choosing one of the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One really easy way to cache data is to just Serialize your objects and save them to the internal cache e.g:

```
// Example object which implements Serializable 
Example example = new Example();

// Save an object 
ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getCacheDir(),"")+"cacheFile.srl"));
out.writeObject((Example) example);
out.close();


// Load in an object
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(new File(getCacheDir(),"")+"cacheFile.srl")));
Example example_loaded = (Example) in.readObject();
in.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your web service gives you an XML or JSON, you can just save it on a file, and then read it from the file. It's like "caching" data.